# g++ 5.5 not linking shared library

Tags: c++, linker, g++, shared-libraries

I'm trying to port a simple program `code.cpp` linked to a couple of shared libraries `libA.so` and `libB.so` from my personal computer (running up-to-date Arch Linux installation) on a machine with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Compiling the libraries works just fine, but I get a lot `undefined reference` errors when compiling `code.cpp`.

I suspect this is being caused by the fact that `libA.so` is linked to `libB.so`, and while both `libA.so` and `libB.so` compile OK on Ubuntu 16.04, strangely `libA.so` does not get linked against `libB.so`, despite the compilation flag `-lB`, which in turns causes undefined references when generating the binary. On the other hand, on Arch Linux `libA.so` does get linked against `libB.so`, or so `ldd` tells me.

I initially though the problem could be mismatched GCC versions, but even after installing and using GCC 8 on Ubuntu 16.04 the problem persists.

Comment: Needs a [mcve] if you want an actual answer.

Answer (score 1):

1. No one guarantees the complete compatibility not only between different Linux distributions, but even between different versions of the same Linux distribution. There was an attempt to unify it called LSB, but unfortunately it failed dramatically.
2. Different C++ compilers often have incompatible C++ libraries. This is also a big pain.
3. I will strongly recommend to recommend you to recompile everything on the target platform.
4. There is ambiguity about loading shared libraries. For some systems if you link a library A which is linked with library B will make symbols of the library B available for your program. For some systems it is not so.

Comment: Thanks for the input. But regarding 2) I have tried to use the same compiler (GCC v8) and had no success; 3) I am recompiling everything on the target machine, the issue is that the resulting shared objects exhibit different links; 4) Curiously, if I directly copy `libA.so` from my original platform (correctly linked to `libB.so`), then everything works.

Comment: Generally you cannot rely on it. Especially with a C++ code. Your friends here are 2 programs: ldd and nm. Check what is missing.